# Adding text to loop in python

Tags: python, loops, variables

I am curios how to do this in Python, Powershell no prob. Python will be the death of me.
Say I have a loop that prints a range, such as

`print"\n".join(['{0:04}'.format(num) for num in xrange(0, 10000)])`

This of course will return a list of

0000
0001
0002
0003
..... 9999

I am curious how to pipe this, or set the string as a variable so I could get reoccurring text before each joined string. Example, Test0000  Test0001 Test0002 .... Test9999. You get the picture.
I have set it as a variable and experimented with that, but I cannot seem to get how to include the Test in the joined string. My results so far have ended up with Test0000 0001 0002 blah blah blah.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: what about `'Test{0:04}'.format(num) ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
print"\n".join(['Test{0:04}'.format(num) for num in xrange(0, 10000)])
```

Comment: @Tim It's all good dude. We all have those days, take it easy

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` too:

Python 3:

```
print('\n'.join(map(lambda x: 'Test{0:04}'.format(x), range(0, 10000))))
```

Python 2:

```
print '\n'.join(map(lambda x: 'Test{0:04}'.format(x), xrange(0, 10000)))
```